# Passing table name in All filter is not working as expected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In order to over write the filter context in calculate DAX formula  ,
I am trying to pass one connected table name in the all function in calculate filter DAX  measure .

My Data is looking like below:

[image]

and my  existing measure is :

```
Measure_Fixed_Parameter = 
    CALCULATE(
        sum('Fact Table'[Output count])
        ,all('Fact Table'[Category])
        ,all('Fact Table'[Sub Category])
    )
```

But Instead of hard coding the all function column names , I wan to pass the table name in the parameter. For this purpose I created separate table with parameter column name and one connecting key column to connect with my Fact table. The Parameter table looks like this.

[image]

The purpose of doing this is to enable end user to update parameter table  manually in excel and get it refreshed from power bi .This will give  flexibility to have  control on the All function column name when ever there is change in the the number of column to be included in the All function. End user no need to update he measure .Instead user can simply update the Parameter table in excel  and get it refreshed from Power BI

The new measure looks like below:

```
Measure_Dynamic_Parameter = 
    CALCULATE(
        sum('Fact Table'[Output count])
        ,all('Parameter Table')
    )
```

This is not working. This is not removing the column filter:

[image]

Is there any way to pass the parameter in the All function .

I know this can be done  if I am making one duplicate table keeping only the parameter column and connect with Fact table with key .But it will be manual work when it comes millions of records

### Pleas help me to find a way how to pass parameter in to All function column name  or how to handle this with table name so that user can update the column in excel without much manual task

Using Power Query I reshaped my Parameter table

I brought my Parameter table in this way:

[image]

and my Fact table in this form changing the key as unique

[image]

and my new measure is :

```
Measure_Fixed_Parametre = 
    CALCULATE(
        sum('tb_Fact_Final'[Output count])
        ,all('tb_Fact_Final'[Category])
    )

Measure_Dynamic_Parametre_New = 
    CALCULATE(
        sum('tb_Fact_Final'[Output count])
        ,ALL('tb_Parameter Table')
    )
```

The dynaic  measure is removing all the filter irresptive of Cateory..How to handle this.please hlep...I am expecting the result lik Measure_Fixed_Parametre

[image]

Comment: On first sight I'd say - you can't. To make a more user frendly interface you can create a selective measure and work with it. But frankly speaking, your problem is not obious, it's hard to advice a good solution for you. Can discribe your case more clear? In a simple way.

Comment: May be you can fix the case with a Power Query.

Comment: Using Power query I reshaped my Parameter table:

Comment: I just updated the steps I have done using Power query

Comment: Why is not `ALL` working as expected? If that is not the question, perhaps the title should be changed. I believe `ALL` is working exactly as it should in your example.